# Angular2 - cannot display json objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript

my boss decided to implement Angular2 into our project. I'm preety new to this technology. I'm trying to display JSON from url, but the result is not as I expected. *ngFor doesn't display any data.

This is the code:

**vehicle.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getVehicle() {
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }}
```

**vehicle.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { VehicleService } from './vehicle.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'vehicle-json',
    templateUrl: 'vehicle.html',
    providers: [ VehicleService ]
})
export class VehicleComponent  { 
  vehicle: Vehicle[];

  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService){
    this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
        /*console.log(vehicle);*/this.vehicle = vehicle;
    });
  }
}

interface Vehicle {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

**vehicle.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
    <h3>{{vehicle.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{vehicle.body}}</p>
</div>
test 1-2-3
```

The output is: "test 1-2-3". I checked if the jsons will be displayed inside the console using: `console.log(vehicle);` - it worked, it returns Array of Objects.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas how to fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error:

```
this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
})
```

but in your html you refer to `let vechicle of vehicles`

You should add an "s" to your `this.vehicle` to your subscription like so:

```
this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
        this.vehicles = vehicle;
})
```

Edit: Just forgot to meantion to change the local variable `vehicle: Vehicle[]` to `vechicles: Vehicle`, but that you figured out that yourself! ;)

Comment: Hey, it works! I changed `vehicle: Vehicle[]` to `vehicles: Vehicle[];` and applied your suggestion. I feel ashamed I made such a small mistake. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes you just need fresh eyes! :)